# Стилизация страницы успешного оформления заказа

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Как в `woocommerce` создать свой шаблон для страницы, формируемой с помощью шорткода `[woocommerce_checkout]`?
те. по умолчанию на этой странице открывается такой шаблон: `page.php`, а в нем подключается шаблон `get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'page' );`
Создавал такие шаблоны в корне темы:
thankyou.php
page-thankyou.php
checkout.php
page-checkout.php
но не работает

Comment: уже понял как, нужно создать примерно так: page-[alias_of_woocommerce_checkout].php